# Replace newline with comma and space to produce 1 line output

Tags: linux, cygwin, tr

Sample file

```
[user@linux ~]$ cat ip.txt
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
[user@linux ~]$
```

1st attempt with 1 space after `,`

```
[user@linux ~]$ tr '\n' ', ' < ip.txt
10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3,[user@linux ~]$
```

2nd attempt with 1 space before and after `,`

```
[user@linux ~]$ tr '\n' ' , ' < ip.txt
10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3 [user@linux ~]$
[user@linux ~]$
```

3rd attempt with 1 space before `,` also producing the same output as 2nd attempt

```
[user@linux ~]$ tr '\n' ' ,' < ip.txt
10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3 [user@linux ~]$
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Update**

`sed` doesn't change anything

```
[user@linux ~]$ sed 's/\n/, /g' ip.txt
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
[user@linux ~]$
```

While `perl` output is similar with attempt 2 & 3

```
[user@linux ~]$ perl -pe 's/\n/ /g' ip.txt
10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3 [user@linux ~]$
```

**Desired Output**

1 space after `,` in one line like this ...

```
10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.2, 10.1.1.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `tr` can only replace a character with another one and it can't be used to insert more characters. Try it with this

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ip.txt
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/\n/, /g' ip.txt
```

If you want to escape the last comma, then

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ip.txt | sed 's/\n$//g'
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. `sed` didn't change anything, while `perl` output is similar with attempt 2 & 3

Comment: Can you make sure that it doesn't work. I tried it on different shells on my machine and it gives the output you desire... I'll research a bit to see another way

Comment: Can you try with this `perl -pe 's/\n/, /g' ip.txt`

Comment: That work, but how do I remove the last `,`. Here is the output of that command `10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.2, 10.1.1.3, `

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ip.txt` try this  as well. As for removing the last comma, you can't because it will also replace the last `\n` character at the end of the file. But let me look into that as well :)

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ip.txt | sed 's/\n$//g'` try this now

Comment: Wow .. the latest `sed` command works! Thanks. Please update your answer so that other would be able to see it as well. I'll accept it.

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ip.txt`

Answer (score 0):

tr can be used to replace only one character with one.

You can’t replace with two characters.

You may search with sed or awk